# Can I legally post my solution to a company's coding test?

Tags: discussion

I had to do a coding test as part of the interview process for a job. The company didn't give me any feedback, though, and just told me they wouldn't be proceeding with my application.

Can I legally post the test's requirements and my solution here to seek advice?

Comment: IANAL, but there's multiple precedents of that on site, so other people definitely did that already.

Comment: Depends on the company. Did they have you agree to anything before you wrote it and sent it to them? For companies like Google for example, then no you should not post your solution here.

Comment: I didn't agree to anything. The PDF with the details of the challenge doesn't have any fine text or legalese.

Comment: **If** you wrote all the code yourself (i.e. you weren't given a skeleton with bits to fill in), **and** you give the problem statement in your own words, **and** you did not agree an exclusive license or assignment of the copyright on your code to anyone, **then** you should be fine.  If you have doubts, ask (and pay) an actual lawyer for legal advice - my assertions are worth approximately what you paid me for them....